# In what scenario would consume() restore default behavior?

Tags: java, swing

When incorporating the following code in a simple program, it stops the cursor from moving (when using the left/right arrows) when inside a cell of a JTable when in edit mode as expected.

```
        public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {  
            if ( (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_KP_LEFT) ||  (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_KP_RIGHT)  
                                    || (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT) || (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT) )   
            {  
                //Do nothing  
                e.consume();  
            }  
        }             
    });
```

Using the same code above to override different behavior in a different program there were unexpected results.

Before incorporating the code, the left/right arrow keys would move to the next cell when in edit mode. After incorporating the code above, the default behavior was restored instead of it disabling the left/right keys as in the basic sample.

Since a sample can't be provided I am wondering in what scenarios would the e.consume() restore default functionality?

Comment: Please add a simple and yet functional piece of code, which input is provided to the code, what is the output of the code, and what were you expecting.

Comment: Probably when the components are using the, preferred, [key bindings](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html) API

Comment: -1, Crossposted: http://www.coderanch.com/t/635617/GUI/java/scenario-consume-restore-default-behavior and the OP will not post a SSCCE as has been asked and Key Bindings have already been mentioned and the tutorial has already been linked to.

Answer (score 0):

After further digging and decompiling the 3rd party code the behavior is a bit more clear.

The main application (MyApp) used a JTable.
A cell withinb JTable uses a custom cell editor (MyEditor).

The custom cell editor (MyEditor) used a 3rd Party object to do the editing (3rdPartyObj_1)

The 3rd Party object (3rdParyObj_1) extends another 3rd Party object (3rdPartyObj_2)

The 3rd Party object (3rdParyObj_2) extends JComponent.

The 3rd Party object (3rdParyObj_2) processes the call: 
    processKeyEvent 
as well as calls:
    super.processKeyEvent

The code listed in the original post is placed within the MyEditor object.

As a test, I created my own class My_JComponent and extended JComponent. 
The method is processKeyEvent which doesn't do anything. 
(Sure I could have simply commented out the call to super but this allowed me to play around further.)

If JComponent prevented from calling processKeyEvent then all works as expected where the cursor key movement moves between characters in edit mode. Essentially I don't even need the above code.

It almost appears as JComponent is processing the arrow key as a tab key automatically or as default processing.